# Git: abandon bad commit and make HEAD the mainstream

Tags: git, git-detached-head

[image]I made some changes to this repository and checked them in and pushed (4326b5, "Waypoint"), before falling back to the previous well behaved commit, 64b7d01 "Merge commit". Then I made some changes from that point and they solved a lot of bugs I had been having. Not going to let that get lost! Now, how to untangle the mess?

Scenario one: yesterday. I had a bunch of changes that I wanted to keep, and I had HEAD at "merge commit". What I really wanted to do was abandon "waypoint" and set master pointing to "merge commit". Reading online it seemed that the advice was to git reset --soft HEAD. However, this accomplished absolutely nothing. What was the right way to do that?

Scenario two: today. Rather than risk my valuable changes, I went ahead and did a commit on the detached head. Now, nearly the same question: how can I get master and origin/master both pointing to bc35e77 "Correctly reports" and abandon "Waypoint" as a detached head or irrelevant branch or something of the sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have push permissions on the master branch remote repo, then you can do the following:

- Save your HEAD state by creating a branch at it. `git branch newfix`
- Switch to the local master branch `git checkout master`.
- Reset master to newfix. `git reset --hard newfix`.
- Push master (You'll lose the "Waypoint" state) `git push --force`

Comment: What does "You'll "Waypoint" state" mean? I can't even parse that.

Comment: @Joymaker I was missing something, and rephrased that now.